# Struct with sections to organize the data

Tags: rust

If I have access to an API and get the data back as JSON, how do I organize it and use it in my Rust code? I'm trying to understand how to create a struct with sections. For example, to create a struct like this:

```
struct mainstruct {
   section1 : {
      brand : "something",
      price : "whatever",
   },
   section2 : {
     title : "here",
     description : "many",         
   },
}
```

Do I create two `impl`s with the two sections and include them in a new struct?
Do I create two `enum`s and include those `enum`s in a new struct?

I get the data from a dummy API with the following code:

```
use reqwest::{Client, Error};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Product {
    pub id: i64,
    pub title: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub price: i64,
    pub rating: f64,
    pub stock: i64,
    pub brand: String,
    pub category: String,
    pub thumbnail: String,
    pub images: Vec<String>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let product: Product = Client::new()
        .get("https://dummyjson.com/products/1")
        .send()
        .await?
        .json()
        .await?;
    println!(">>>>>  Brand is : {:#?}", product.brand);
    Ok(())
}
```

How can I create a some type of data that organize/present it like this?

```
info {
  price : Product.price,
  category : Product.category,
},
data {
  title : Product.title,
  description : Product.description,
}
```

Comment: There isn't much difference between how you would model nested data in Rust vs any other language. Each "section" looks like its own struct, and the parent struct would contain a field for each of them. If the nested data is an enum, create an enum. If the nested data is a dictionary of named fields, its probably best to use a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Rust doesn't support nested struct definitions; they'll need to be separate if that's what you want:

```
struct Product {
    info: ProductInfo,
    data: ProductData,
}

struct ProductInfo {
    brand: String,
    price: i64,
    /* ... */
}

struct ProductData {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    /* ... */
}
```

Though now this structure is different from the JSON structure from the API. In this case you can be clever by using `#[serde(flatten)]` ([demo on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa1578d54cca6950b3ab6da03f8f5744)).

But if that is not appropriate you may need to have separate type definitions for your "domain" (what you want to use internally) and "data transfer" (only used to interface with something else) and probably implement `From` to define conversions between each other ([demo on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4273d4a59cfe875a3f6bc2aa4563e1aa)).

Comment: That is easy for someone like me - new to rust - to be able to segment the data and use it anyway in the rust code. I'm not familiar with serde(flatten) and will need to read more about that to understand what it does. Thank you.